# How to get values of all keys in array of objects with more than one keys and then sum of them all

Tags: javascript

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [
  { value1: 50, },
  { value2: 100, value3: 600 },
  { value4: 500, value5: 700 }
];


for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
  var key = Object.values(arrayOfObjects[i]);
  var sum = 0;

  for (var j = 0; j < key.length; j++) {
    var key = Object.values(arrayOfObjects[j]);
    var string = key[j];
    var sum = sum + (string);
    console.log(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` in combination with `Object.values` to get a flattened array of all values. Then you can sum them with `reduce`:

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [
  { value1: 50, },
  { value2: 100, value3: 600 },
  { value4: 500, value5: 700 }
];
var total = arrayOfObjects
  .flatMap(Object.values)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(total);
```

Comment: _"...with more than one key..."_

Comment: @Andreas I'm not sure what you mean. The objects in the array can have any number of keys and this should take care of that...

Comment: The "requirement" is: _"How to get values of all keys in array of objects with **more than one** keys..."_

Comment: @Andreas Oh I see the confusion now. I interpreted it as objects that could have any number of keys but you're saying only those objects with at least 2 keys.

Comment: Now i want the same thing without using builtin functions

Answer (score 0):

Use reduce

```
  var arrayOfObjects = [
  { value1: 50, },
  { value2: 100, value3: 600 },
  { value4: 500, value5: 700 }
];

const sum = arrayOfObjects.reduce((total, current) => {
    const values = Object.values(current);
    return values.length > 1 ? values.reduce((last, next) => last + next, 0) + total : total
}, 0)
```

[Stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ma6b7f)

Comment: Now i want the same thing without using builtin functions